# prove command not passing arguments after arisdottle to

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing, perl-prove

I'm trying to pass some parameters to a test script *through* the `prove` command. Based on some old threads where is option was hashed out, and the content's of my prove's `man` page (quoted below), using :: before the options should work, but prove is still parsing the test script's option as it's own:

> $ `prove -v t/040-unit-object-test.t :: --unit 270149`
>   `Unknown option: unit`

Here the relevant part of the man page:

> ```
>    Arguments to Tests
>
>   It is possible to supply arguments to tests. To do so separate them
>   from prove's own arguments with the arisdottle, '::'. For example
>
>    prove -v t/mytest.t :: --url http://example.com
>
>   would run t/mytest.t with the options '--url http://example.com'.  When
>   running multiple tests they will each receive the same arguments.
> ```

I tried using `sudo` to run the option as root, but got the same error.

I am using the Getopt::Long module to get the options, and the options work when I run the test script using plain old `perl`, but then my SKIP and TODO blocks don't work.

I would rather not have to use the `--exec` workaround.

I'm running Perl 5.10 on Mac OS 10.6.

The output of `prove -V` is:

> `prove v2.64, using Test::Harness v3.25 and Perl v5.10.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you must have two versions of `prove` in your $PATH, an old one from 2006 from before App::Prove existed

I suggest you delete that one, and re-install App::Prove

Comment: You were right. I actually had 3 versions of `prove`. The latest one, from Nov. 2009, allowed passing of arguments through to test scripts. (Even stranger, when I type `man prove`, I get the man page from a 2012 version.)

Comment: OK, when I run my newer copy of `prove`, it's using a different copy of `perl`, which doesn't have all the modules I need installed. Do I have to install all the modules again, for the newer copy of perl, can I "uninstall" the prove from the /usr/bin directory and update it without updating the whole Perl installation?